# which CSS selector after a br-tag

Tags: css

how is the selector for the  "item b" in this sample:

```
<td class="col_3">item before br-tag <br/> flexible item after br-tag</td>
```

This is not working:

```
td.col_3  > br 
{display: none;}
```

Comment: What you have will select that br element correctly. But I'm actually not sure if display:none has any effect on a br. What if you just stick a div there instead?

Comment: the css parameter is only a sample. Actually I like to use background-color:gray; later. I am trying to find out how to select the second element...

Comment: td.col_3  > br 
{background-color:gray;}

Comment: I think you are confused about what a br tag is and possibly what the selector is selecting. A br tag is just a line break. It doesn't contain anything. It can't be styled.

Comment: ,,, the <td> </td> contains the data, but I need style only the part  after </br>. Is there not any version of td:first-child > br ?

Comment: I would play around with some css tutorials to understand a bit more about how selectors work. The > means "find a child directly owned by".  You might get close to something you want with td.col_3::first-line or ::first-word, but your best bet is just to use JavaScript to edit the Dom how you want it.

Answer (score 9):

Try using the following CSS selectors:

```
.col_3 { 
   color:red;
 } 
.col_3:first-line { 
   color:gray;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to tell you that there is no selector for text-nodes. Only elements can be targeted with CSS. If you wish to style two text-nodes differently they need to be nested in two different elements.

Is there a problem with nesting your lines in spans?

```
<span>line 1</span><br>
<span>line 2</span>
```

You could then target line 2 with `br + span {}` or alternatively `span:last-child {}`

---

Edit: Now that I know you want a gray background, what you can do is place a semi-transparent area over it, like this (You may have to adjust the height):

```css
.col_3 {
  position:relative;
  background:white;
}
.col_3::before {
  content:' ';
  position:absolute;
  background:black;
  opacity:.5;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="col_3">Line 1<br>Line 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ... .. unfortunately the site does not allow editing the text. I can only access via an external CSS-File to this structure: <td class="wholeterm">part term a<br/> flexible part term b</td>   Is there maybe something like a divider-selector in css differenciating after a br-tag?

Comment: Thank you this sounds a good way,  however I can not add any span-tag, since its a cms, I only can address via external css. Is there maybe  a version with jquery?

Comment: No, there is no way to target text-nodes, but please see my edit for a workaround.